# Unit test service worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I Want to know if there is library specific to unit test the service-worker.Or if there is any way to mock the install and other events to check wheather it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should have googled first, right? :-)

Read [this](https://medium.com/dev-channel/testing-service-workers-318d7b016b19) excellent article by Matt Gaunt of Google and check out how one of the bigger Service Worker libraries, SW Toolbox implements their library testing over [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/tree/master/test).

Comment: Thanks, btw I checked this article before posting this question, but my aim is to get more recommendation on it

Comment: Ha! Ok! I suppose next time you should tell that in your question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a package `service-worker-mock`. [service-worker-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-worker-mock)

I believe this material would be a great reference point
[Service Worker Testing Made Easy](https://hackernoon.com/service-worker-testing-made-easy-9a2d8e9aa50)